# Posting frequencies of the contents of a dictionary in descending order (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I created a dictionary that counts the number of occurrences of each word in a separate text file. So far it looks like this.

```
import sys

def main():
    d = dict({})
    
    with open(sys.argv[1], encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for line in f: 
            line = line.strip() 
            line = line.lower() 
            words = line.split(" ")
            for word in words: 
                if word in d: 
                    d[word] = d[word] + 1
                else: 
                    d[word] = 1
    
    for key in list(d.keys()):
        print(key, ":", d[key])
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the command line, I input a text file for it to count the frequencies of each word (executing "python3 frequencycount.py example.txt"). This code effectively executes a list of all words in the text file and it counts how many times they occur. What I'm trying to do ***now*** is print the words in descending order by frequency of occurrence.

For example, my text file is a list of vegetables (pepper 5 times, carrot 9 times, peas 8 times, and broccoli 1 time). The list looks like this:

```
Pepper : 5
Carrot : 9
Peas : 8
Broccoli : 1
```

However, I would want it to print like this:

```
Carrot : 9
Peas : 8
Pepper : 5
Broccoli : 1
```

How can I make it print in descending order like this? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a `collections.Counter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over a sorted list of keys, where the sort key is the values of the dict itself, with `reverse=True` making it descending order.

```
d = {
'Pepper' : 5,
'Carrot' : 9,
'Peas' : 8,
'Broccoli' : 1,
}


for key in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True):
    print(key, ":", d[key])
```

Output

```
Carrot: 9
Peas : 8
Pepper : 5
Broccoli : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for i in d:
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

Comment: [Other examples if you need them](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value/)